# Stateless/Stateful Service OnPre. OnPost Service Methods | Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Like actors have a pre and post method for any Interface method in an Actor service like below
protected override Task OnPreActorMethodAsync(ActorMethodContext c)
protected override Task OnPostActorMethodAsync(ActorMethodContext c)

Do we have anything similar for a Stateless Service and Statuful Service. The intention is to know if a method has been entered and when it leaves that method.

Answer (score 0):

No. Actors run within a special framework that does some magic around method execution (like enforcing single-threaded access). Stateless and stateful services don't run in any sort of framework. They are literally just regular .NET objects.